# Trying to find the square root but am getting a math domain error

Tags: python

I think my code should be working but why do I keep getting a domain error?

```
from math import sqrt

x1 = float(input("Enter the x1"))

x2 = float(input("Enter the x2"))

y1 = float(input("Enter the y1"))

y2 = float(input("Enter the y2"))

x_distance = x2 - x1**2

y_distance = y2 - y1**2

distance = x_distance + y_distance

print math.sqrt(distance)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x_distance = x2 - x1**2
```

is wrong. You need parenthesis around `(x2 - x1)`. The formula is

```
distance = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
```

so you need

```
x_distance = (x2 - x1)**2
y_distance = (y2 - y1)**2
```

instead.

In your case you get a domain error because probably you end up with a negative distance.

PS: also replace `math.sqrt` with `sqrt`, as you already imported it.

<kbd>[Live example](https://repl.it/BJl3)</kbd>

Comment: I tried putting in your code but it did not work either! Would you be able to send me an edited version of my code? Btw isn't there supposed to be 2 x and 2 y values?

Comment: @KarlRamos It works fine on my end, what do you mean it doesn't work? See the live example in which it works just fine.

Comment: yes it is working for me now but when I complete it I get the wrong answer. Here is what I inputted: x1 = 3 x2 = 4 y1 = 5 y2 = 6

Comment: @KarlRamos the distance in this case is `sqrt(2)`, which is correct.

Comment: oh thanks I was using another website to calculate it and I guess it was giving me the wrong answer then thanks for your help!